# Why do I get a different value when invoking request.contextPath() in JSP and in SpringMVC controller

Tags: java, jsp

I am using Tomcat Server and SpringMVC. In my all JSP files, I used `request.contextPath()` to set the root path of my resource, like this:

```
<c:set var="root" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${root}/js/selectator/fm.selectator.jquery.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="${root}/js/selectator/fm.selectator.jquery.js"></script>
```

And in my controller, when I upload an image, my cloud save interface will return a `cloudFileId`, and I will generate a request url for this image and return the url to the browser, so that I can insert an `<img>` element with this url in JSP field, my code here is:

```
if (Detect.notEmpty(cloudFileId)) {
                json.put("url", request.getContextPath() + GET_FILE_URL + cloudFileId);
                json.put("state", "SUCCESS");
            }
```

The problem is: when the JSP is loaded, `${root}` is all replaced with `""` cause I set Context root "/" in the Web Project Setting in Eclipse, while the url of that image is added something like "/myProject".

Why do I get a different value when invoking the same method? How can I get "" too when invoking request.getContextPath() in SpringMVC controller?

Comment: Why don't just use `<c:url>`?

Comment: I want to add the root context in my SpringMVC controller, is there anything I can do?@W-S

Comment: Have you debug or print out the value of `request.getContextPath()` in your controller? And what is the value of `GET_FILE_URL`?

Comment: Yeah, I have, the value is like `/myProject`.  As for `GET_FILE_URL`, it is a servlet path, like `/getFile`, when requesting this url, this servlet method accept a parameter fileId and return a `byte[]` @W-S